# How to zend 2 unit test a select query take argument as Closure

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, zend-framework2, closures

I'm new with php unit and Zend 2.

I need to write unit test for the function below:

```
public function getMyList($limitDay)
{
        // build time
        $limitTime = strtotime("-".$limitDay." day"); // UNIX timestamp
        $timeStr = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $limitTime); // format time

        // run query
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(
                // use closure
                function (Select $select) use ($timeStr) {
                    $condition = function (Where $where) use($timeStr) {
                        $where->greaterThan('SEND_TIME', new Expression('TIMESTAMP \''.$timeStr.'\''));
                    };
                    $select->where($condition);
                }
        );

        return $resultSet;
}
```

As ZF2 document for unit test, I can create a unit test function like this:

```
public function testGetMyList()
{
        $resultSet = new ResultSet();
        $mockTableGateway = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway',
                                           array('select'), array(), '', false);
        $mockTableGateway->expects($this->once())
                         ->method('select')
                         ->with(/*[argument]*/)
                         ->will($this->returnValue($resultSet));

        $albumTable = new AlbumTable($mockTableGateway);

        $this->assertSame($resultSet, $albumTable->getMyList(1));
}
```

But I don't know how to describe Closure

```
                function (Select $select) use ($timeStr) {
                    $condition = function (Where $where) use($timeStr) {
                        $where->greaterThan('SEND_TIME', new Expression('TIMESTAMP \''.$timeStr.'\''));
                    };
                    $select->where($condition);
                }
```

for

```
/*[argument]*/
```

There's no tutorial for describe it or create mock for Closure.

Please help me in this case! Thank you

Comment: The closure is inside the unit you want to test, therefore you don't need to mock it. It's an implementation detail.

Comment: so how do I write unit test for getMyList function?

Comment: You test a method normally by invoking it and asserting the return value. Keep tests simple. Do only one assertion per test. If creating the Mock is complicated, move creating the mock into a helper function or `setUp()`.

Comment: But the tableGateway need mock to test, so I must describe it

Comment: Well, maybe. However I wonder a little what you want to test here. Do you want to test the first two lines that the string formatting is working? Or do you want to test that `tableGateway::select()` works? As the later is part of Zend Framework2, this should have already been tested, so don't write new unit-tests for it in your application (if not tested, write unit-tests in the zend framework 2 testsuite for it and make a pull-request). Also for the string functions, looks like they are tested in PHP as well. So what actually do you want to test here?????

Comment: Many thank you for your time. I want to test that with argument $limitDay, a right Select query is built. So I think I can use the mock technique to simulate the $resultSet return value if select query is built right, as tutorial of ZF2 for unit test http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#testing-model-tables. The problem is I don't know the way to write code to check the Select query.

Comment: I'm not a ZF2 specialist. I don't know as well. Maybe there is some getter / property you can run your assertion on?